# How saving multiple form field text in array with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new in mongoose and node with express, needs you help please..... I have my schema

```
var creditSchema = new Schema({
    mount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    period: Number,
    allDayPay: [{periods: String, dayPay: String, mountPay: String}],
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});
```

and I have a form, this form have a type text that generate depending of number of periods for example, if put 10 period jquery generate 10 text field, this code:

```
$('#calculate').click(function(){

  var period = $("#period").val();// This can be 10 or 15 or 30.....

  for (i = 0; i < period; i++){

    var textPeriod = '
    <input type="text" id="periods'+[i+1]+'" name="periods'+[i+1]+'" value="Pago-'+[i+1]+'" />
    <input type="text" id="dayPay'+[i+1]+'" name="dayPay'+[i+1]+'" value="'+moment(allPay._d).format('LL')+'" />
    <input type="text" id="mountPay'+[i+1]+'" name="mountPay'+[i+1]+'" value="'+mountPay+'" />';

    $('#listAll').append(textPeriod);
  }
});
```

This form is GOOD! no have problem.

I too have this router post trying save data

```
router.post('/saveCredit', function(req, res){
  var credits = new Credits();
  credits.mount = req.body.mount;       
  credits.period = req.body.period;
  credits.allDayPay = [];

  for(i=0; i<=req.body.period; i++){
    credits.allDayPay = [{periods: req.body.periods[i],(dayPay: req.body.dayPay[i], mountPay: req.body.mountPay[i])}];
  };

  credits.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    };
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

I try this method and other methods found in blogs without successfully, The question is how I can save those data (periods, dayPay, mountPay) in the field schema called 'allDayPay'(array), if I do post method??
This should save as this format below.

```
"allDayPay": [
    {
        "periods": 1,
        "dayPay": 12/09/15;
        "mountPay": 150
    },
    {
        "periods": 2,
        "dayPay": 12/10/15;
        "mountPay": 150
    },
    {
        "periods": 3,
        "dayPay": 12/11/15;
        "mountPay": 150
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ...... everything that can be save depending of number of periods specified in the form
]
```

Please explain to me how save this data, Thank youu!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this this may work:

```
for(i=0; i<=req.body.period; i++){
 var temp = '{periods:'+ req.body.periods[i]+',(dayPay: '+req.body.dayPay[i]+', mountPay:'+ req.body.mountPay[i]+')}';
credits.allDayPay.push(temp); 
};
```

Comment: When try this code I have error 'throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');', When I do a console.log(temp) inside array, the object array is good show me all data, but when I do a console.log(credits.allDayPay) or console.log(credits), outside of array the arrays object called 'allDayPay' show me empty [{},{},{},{}.....], I believe that is the error, Now how can do to save all array in allDayPay when call the function credits.save(func....), thank you;